# How to not show tagged revisions in Tortoise HG?

Tags: tortoisehg

Our CI server helpfully tags our repos with a revision number when it runs a build.  The problem is that these tags are uninteresting to me, since no code is changed.
How can I tell Tortoise HG to NOT show any tagged revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the filter toolbar (Ctrl-S) and use either `not tagged()` to eliminate revisions with tags on them, or `not keyword('Added tag')` to remove the entries that create the tags...probably the latter if you just want to eliminate the entries that update `.hgtags`.